# Wake on LAN (WoL) - start computers over the network

Tags: autohotkey, wake-on-lan

You sometimes want to start a computer without pressing it's power button. And it can be done.. over the network using a technology called Wake on LAN (WoL).

But how can it be done in AutoHotkey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wake a computer over your LAN you need to create and send a so called magic packet. All you need to know is the mac address of your target computer. Also, make sure it is [properly set up for WoL](http://windows7-issues.blogspot.de/2011/03/wake-on-lan-wol-for-windows-7-made-easy.html).

Waking the computer can be done pretty easily using the socket library in AHK:

```
#include Socket.ahk ;http://pastebin.com/CtM9p4QG

WakeOnLAN("AABBCCDDEEFF") ;Example  - use the mac address of your target here
ExitApp

WakeOnLAN(mac) {
    magicPacket_HexString := GenerateMagicPacketHex(mac)
    size := CreateBinary(magicPacket_HexString, magicPacket)
    UdpOut := new SocketUDP()
    UdpOut.connect("addr_broadcast", 9)
    UdpOut.enableBroadcast()
    UdpOut.send(&magicPacket, size)
}
GenerateMagicPacketHex(mac) {
    magicPacket_HexString := "FFFFFFFFFFFF"
    Loop, 16
        magicPacket_HexString .= mac
    Return magicPacket_HexString
}
CreateBinary(hexString, ByRef var) { ;Credits to RHCP!
    sizeBytes := StrLen(hexString)//2
    VarSetCapacity(var, sizeBytes)
    Loop, % sizeBytes
        NumPut("0x" SubStr(hexString, A_Index * 2 - 1, 2), var, A_Index - 1, "UChar")
    Return sizeBytes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Softperfect Network Scanner](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/) (the one that has a soccer ball for an icon) and then use AutoHotkey to send commandlines to it.  You can run it portably too, so you don't even need to install anything.

```
netscan := "c:\program files\netscan\netscan.exe"
run, %netscan% /wol:AA:EE:73:43:BB:73
```

The commandline syntax for netscan is at the [bottom of the docs page](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/manual/).

> /wol:MAC sends a Wake-On-LAN magic packet to the specified MAC address
>   and immediately exits. Example: /wol:AABBCCDDEEFF.
>
> /wolfile:filename.txt allows you to specify a text file with MAC
>   addresses to wake-up, e.g. /wolfile:c:\myfile.txt where the file is a
>   plain text file containing one MAC address per line.
>
> /wakeall sends a WOL packet to all computers configured in the WOL
>   manager and immediately quits.

But keep in mind that you have to have the option enabled in your BIOS to enable the computer to receive a magic packet on it's NIC.